# Java `if` statement and `else if` not working as expected

Tags: java, if-statement

I have the user enter a list of 5 ints into an `int[]`. I then go through those ints in the int[] with a simple `for` statement. I have an `int` variable declared called "evens." If the number in the int[] at `i %2 == 0` , `evens++`;

Now I have the `if` statement:

```
if (evens !=2 || evens!=3) {
  System.out.print("This was called because " + evens + " is not equal to 2 or 3");
}
```

The problem is that this is being called no matter what the value in evens is. It can be 5 or 3 and still gets called. I've been using C# recently but this is simple Java.

Whole code:

```
int evens = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<chosenNumbers.length; i++) {
        if(chosenNumbers[i] %2 ==0)
            evens++;
    }

System.out.println("You chose "+evens+" even numbers and " + (chosenNumbers.length-evens) + " odd numbers.");

    if (evens !=2 || evens!=3) {
        System.out.print("This was called because " + evens + " is not equal to 2 or 3");
    } else if (evens==2 || evens==3) {
        System.out.print(evens +" equals 2 or 3");
    }
```

Comment: Try saying `evens !=2 || evens!=3` in English: "if evens differs from 2 **or** evens differs from 3, then ....". And then you'll realize that any number always differs from 2 *or* differs from 5. You probably mean **and** instead of *or*.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace:

```
if(evens !=2 || evens!=3) {
    System.out.print("This was called because " + evens + " is not equal to 2 or 3");
}
```

with:

```
if(evens !=2 && evens!=3) {
    System.out.print("This was called because " + evens + " is not equal to 2 or 3");
}
```

If you use the logical OR `||`, you will always enter the block, as the only way it would not enter is it `evens` is equal to 2 and 3 at the same time, which isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
if(!(evens ==2 || evens==3)) {
        System.out.print("This was called because " + evens + " is not equal to 2 or 3");
} else {
        System.out.print(evens +" equals 2 or 3");
}
```

Comment: @MrAwesome8, not true ... boolean algebra can be correctly applied: `!(a || b)` is equivalent to `!a && !b`. This is part of [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). Devils and Details ...

Comment: @JoD. Exactly, and that's why this answer is "Not Useful" as it gives the same answer as AntonH gave 12 minutes earlier, but without any explanation. There's no need for duplicate answers.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I can agree to that as a reason for flagging/downvoting, but the first comment should be retracted as incorrect.

Comment: Also @Heshan was earlier to respond and did incorporate the simpler else in his answer. That is no need for the `else if (...)`. Would be nice if the poster would highlight that in his answer. If not the accepted answer can highlight that part too.